# Were there US troops on the WW1 eastern front?

Tags: united-states, world-war-one

I would like to know more about the first world war, especially 
about the involvement of the USA on the eastern front. Were there 
any US troops in eastern front present, if so how many? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please review [help] to understand how to ask.  This question has an answer, so it should remain open, but questions should be questions, and should demonstrate prior research.  Welcome to the site, and we look forward to your next question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There were no US troops involved in the Eastern Front of WWI, but they were involved in two campaigns of the [Allied intervention in the Russian Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allied_intervention_in_the_Russian_Civil_War).

In the [north of Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Russia_Intervention#International_contingent), the US Army staged what is known as the [Polar Bear Expedition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Expeditionary_Force,_North_Russia), supported by the USN cruiser [USS Olympia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Olympia_(C-6)#World_War_I).

In the far east of Russia, the [American Expeditionary Force, Siberia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Expeditionary_Force,_Siberia) operated around Vladivostok, but did not fight the Bolsheviks.